Numpy: Move values according to another array
I've tried searching for it for a few hours now, but couldn't find a solution, so I hope someome can help me.
Assuming I have two numpy arrays that look like this:
data_arr = [[0 1 2]
            [1 0 0]]

move_arr = [[(0,0)  (0,0)  (1,0)]
            [(-1,0) (0,-1) (0,0)]]

I need to find a way to move the values within data_arr according to the values in move_arr. The rules for this are as follows: If the value in data_arr is 0, or if the destination of the movement in data_arr is not 0, the movement is ignored. (Example code below)
The expected result would be:
new_data_arr = [[1 1 0]
                [0 0 2]]

Please note that in reality, the arrays I'm working with are massive and that this is performance critical code. Therefore, I can't just use for loops.
So I have to ask, whether or not this, or at least something similar to it, is doable quickly. And if it is, then how?
I already tried using for loops, and while it kind of worked, it was simply WAY too slow.
Edit for further clarification:
new_data_arr is an array with the same shape as data_arr and move_arr and contains only 0
If a movement value of move_arr points toward something that is outside of data_arr / new_data_array, the movement shouldn't happen, but it's also okay if the movement is transferred onto the corresponding  other side of the 2d array.
So putting it all together:
import numpy as np

def move(data_arr, move_arr):
    # get the shape and create new_data_arr
    height, width = np.shape(data_arr)
    new_data_arr = np.zeros((height, width))
    # iterate over the array
    for y in range(height):
        for x in range(width):
            # get the movement destination
            target_y = y + move_arr[y, x][0]
            target_x = x + move_arr[y, x][1]
            # if the movement is zero, and the destination is not already obstructed,
            # and the destination is also not obstructed from a previous movement:
            if not np.all(move_arr[y, x], 0) and data_arr[target_y, target_x] == 0 and new_data_arr[target_y, target_x] == 0:
                # assign the value from data_arr to the destination in new_data_arr
                new_data_arr[target_y, target_x] = data_arr[y, x]
            # elif the value is not zero: (so that zeros don't overwrite already moved values)
            elif data_arr[y, x] != 0:
                # copy data onto the same place
                new_data_arr[y, x] = data_arr[y, x]
    return new_data_arr

# Example:
data_arr = np.array([[0,1,2],[1,0,0]])
move_arr = np.array([[(0,0), (0,0), (1,0)], [(-1,0), (0,-1), (0,0)]])

new_data_arr = move(data_arr, move_arr)

print(new_data_arr)


Please explain better the logic. How do you get new_data_arr using those values? and what do you mean by 0 in move_arr? (0, 0)?

What do the -1 represent?

And post the code you have so far, even if it's not working as expected.

What should be the result if two different non-0 cells want to move to the same place?

@AndrejKesely I now provided some example code for how it works.

@killer you should be able to speed this up using numba as demonstrated in my answer

@killer Is the movement only +/- 1? Or is there bigger step?

@AndrejKesely No, the movements can be of greater size. There is no actual upper limit (except for the array's size)

Assuming numpy arrays as input, you can use numba to perform this operation with loops efficiently:
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def move(data_arr, move_arr):
    out = data_arr.copy()
    for i in range(data_arr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(data_arr.shape[1]):
            i2, j2 = move_arr[i, j]
            i2 += i
            j2 += j
            if out[i, j] != 0 and out[i2, j2] == 0:
                out[i2, j2], out[i, j] = data_arr[i, j], data_arr[i2, j2]
    return out

out = move(data_arr, move_arr)

Output:
array([[1, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 2]])

Used inputs:
data_arr = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
                     [1, 0, 0]])

move_arr = np.array([[(0,0), (0,0), (1,0)],
                     [(-1,0), (0,-1), (0,0)]])


I heard about numba before. It compiles your function into machine code, right? I'd like to test it, but I'm not home currently and only have my phone with me. The IDE's pip throws a massive error message when I try to install it... It also put a note below it: 'Note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.'

Yes, it compiles your function.
